# Is there any API to donate money by iTunes account?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5

I am preparing an App for charity on iOS. PayPal is my first choice.
I cannot assume all users have Paypal but I am sure all of them have iTunes account.

Can I let user donate to charity by entering iTune account username and password?

Apple support [Red Cross donation for Japan quake](http://www.tuaw.com/2011/03/13/apple-now-accepts-donations-to-red-cross-japan-relief-fund-via-i/).Has Apple open this kind of API?

Comment: You can also use iAP (In App Purchase)

Comment: Will apple charge 30% for donation?

Comment: @sanchitsingh Unless you have information to the contrary, I don't think they'll allow donations via iAP. You could probably sell merchandise (on a non-tax-free basis) generating earned income for the charity, but you probably won't be able to do donations via iAP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update:

[US non-profits can accept donations via Apple Pay](https://developer.apple.com/support/apple-pay-nonprofits/):

> Starting November 14, 2016, nonprofits based in the United States can use Apple Pay to provide a simple and secure way to accept donations from within their app and website. Similar to using Apple Pay to buy goods and services, users can donate without entering their billing, shipping, or contact details.

The [App Store guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) go on to say:

> Acceptable
>
> Approved nonprofits may fundraise directly within their own apps using Apple Pay, provided those fundraising campaigns adhere to all App Review Guidelines. These apps must disclose how the funds will be used, abide by all required local and federal laws, and make appropriate tax receipts available to donors. Nonprofit platforms that connect donors to other nonprofits must ensure that every nonprofit listed in the app has also gone through the nonprofit approval process. Learn more about becoming an approved nonprofit.
>
> Unacceptable
>
> Unless you are an approved nonprofit, collecting funds within the app for charities and fundraisers. Apps that seek to raise money for such causes must be free on the App Store and may only collect funds outside of the app, such as via Safari or SMS.

My old answer, below, predated this revision in the charitable giving policy.

---

Not only do they not have an API, but they seem to explicitly preclude the possibility of doing so. See Section 21 of the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html):

> 21 Charities and contributions
>
> 21.1 Apps that include the ability to make donations to recognized charitable organizations must be free
>
> 21.2 The collection of donations must be done via a web site in Safari or an SMS

I'm not quite sure why they do this (maybe an accounting issues around 501(c)(3) organizations).

Anyway, initiate a SMS via [MFMessageComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) or pass as many of the user parameters as possible to a web page in Safari via

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlForDonation]];
```

Comment: Thank your help. Even I created a webpage and redirect user, I didn't find iTunes work like an open-id to authenticate payment.

but at least I have to create UIWebView or pop safari for App approval.